# Множественное число слова « юла»

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, множественное-число

Игрушка "волчок" — это юла. А как будет во множественном числе?

Answer (score 1):

[Юла](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B0) — это не только игрушка.
Во множественном числе слово имеет [такие формы](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%3Cspan%20class=&start=420):
И. п. — юлы́
Р. п. — юл (возможная форма)
Д. п. — юла́м
В. п. — юлы́ (в знач. "волчок"), юл (в значении "егоза", "птица")
Т. п. — юла́ми
П. п. — о юла́х

Синиц он ценил только большеголовых, у которых полоса черная шла от шейки через всю желтую грудку, была нерваная, яркая и широкая… А когда с весенних проталин приносил десятки жаворонков, хохлатых и бесхохлых, он очень серьезно разглядывал их каждого порознь, ерошил перья, распускал крылья, примерял на ногте хохолки и шпоры и рассаживал в семейные клетки ― степняков к степнякам, лесняков к леснякам, полевых **юл к юлам**. [С. Н. Сергеев-Ценский. Аракуш (1926)]

*Это были крупные парусные кунгасы с азиатскими веслами — **«юлами»**, которыми не гребут, а мерно вращают, как рыба хвостом* (Венедикт Март. За голубым трепангом).

[Лесной жаворонок, или юла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [викисловарю](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B0) — *юлы́*. Вот вся парадигма:

**Им.** *юла́,  юлы́.*
**Р.**  *юлы́,  юл.*
**Д.**  *юле́,  юла́м.*
**В.**  *юлу́,  юлы́.*
**Тв.** *юло́й/юло́ю, юла́ми.*
**Пр.** *юле́,  юла́х.*